# Custom configuration variable not available when running locally

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have set my variable with `firebase functions:config:set stripe.key="xxxxxxx"`

`firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json` exports config correctly to the functions folder.

```
{
  "stripe": {
    "key": "xxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

However using functions.config().stripe.key returns the error when running `firebase serve`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
at Object. (C:\Users\ash\Documents\GitHub\danceform\functions\index.js:14:38)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at C:\Users\ash\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.5\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:21:11
at Object. (C:\Users\ash\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.11.5\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:75:3)
```

Windows 10

firebase-admin: ^5.13.1,

firebase-functions: ^2.0.2

firebase-tools: 4.0.0

nodejs: 6.11.5

**UPDATE EDIT**

Creating the .runtimeconfig.json file manually with VScode resolves the issue. The problem appears to be when creating the file with firebase functions:config:sget > .runtimeconfig.json (powershell)

Even though both files have the same CR/LF line endings and exactly the same text. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using CMD instead of powershell to do functions:config:get >.runtimeconfig.json